# How to efficiently implement regular expression like .*a.*b.*?

Tags: regex, algorithm, performance

I want to matching of filenames like [Colibri](http://alternativeto.net/software/colibri) does. I tried to solve it by regular expressions.

Searching in Colibri works that You type characters which are in order inside of a filename and it finds all files with these characters in order in the filename. For example for "ab" it finds "cabal", "ab", and "achab".

Simple insertion of `.*` between letters works (so searched string "ab" becomes regular expression `.*a.*b.*`), but I want to make it on large amount of files.

So far I have O(N*???), where N is amount of filenames and ??? is at best linear complexity (I assume my language uses NFA). I don't care about space complexity that much. What data structures or algorithms should I choose to make it more efficient (in time complexity)?

Comment: @user712092 Don't forget to accept an answer if one of them helps you out.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to check whether the characters of a search string *search* are contained in another string *str* in the same order, you could use this simple algorithm:

```
pos := -1
for each character in search do
    pos := indexOf(str, character, pos+1)
    if pos is -1 then
        break
    endif
endfor
return pos
```

This algorithm returns the offset of the last character of *search* in *str* and -1 otherwise. Its runtime is in O(*n*) (you could replace `indexOf` by a simple `while` loop that compares the characters in *str* from *pos* to Length(*str*)-1 and returns either the offset or -1).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about storing what characters are in each word ... :)

Comment: If you stretch a little, this is equivalent to the NFA solution, but without the bundled complexity of the having to handle the general case. You can easily add extra funcionality for checking where each letter matched as well.

Answer (score 4):

It will greatly improve your efficiency if you replace the `.` with a character negation. i.e.

```
 [^a]*a[^b]*b.*
```

This way you have much less backtracking. [See This Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

---

**Edit*** @yi_H you are right, this regex would probably serve just as well:

```
a[^b]*b
```

Comment: drop that extra `.*` at the end

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  +1

Comment: Backtracking? Real regexps don't backtrack. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your `.` is unnecessary.  You'll get better performance if you simply transform "abc"
into `^[^a]*a[^b]*b[^c]*c`.

```
string exp = "^";
foreach (char c in inputString)
{
   string s = Regex.Escape (c.ToString()); // escape `.` as `\.`
   exp += "[^" + s + "]*" + s; // replace `a` with `[^a]*a`
}
Regex regex = new Regex (exp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
{
   if (regex.IsMatch (fileName))
      yield return fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a limited character-set it might make sense to create lookup table which contains an array or linked list of matching filenames.

If your ABC contains X characters then the "1 length" lookup table will contain X table entries, if it is a "2 length" table it will contain X^2 entries and so on. The 2 length table will contain for each entry ("ab", "qx") all the files which which have those letters in that order. When searching for longer input "string" look up the appropriate entry and do the search on those entries.

Note: calculate the needed extra memory and measure the speed improvement (compared to full table scan), the benefits depend on the data set.

Comment: So I should create map from `arbitrary sequence` to `all filenames containing it`?

Comment: For a limited sequence length, yes. You can encode the entry (eg: "exe") as a number, for a simple alphabet this will be a number bethween 0 and 26^3-1. For longer user input drop the most frequent letters of the alphabet and do the lookup for the rest (3 chars). You can store a pointer for the actual filename so it will occupy less space. I don't know how big your dataset is and how long the filenames are, but it doesn't sound so complex, probably worth a try.